# How detailed does a proof have to be and is the format constrained to text and equations?

Tags: soft-question

Given that somebody claims a proof to a problem and you ask 100 highly qualified mathematicians whether this proof is valid, will they all agree that it's valid or all claim it's invalid?

In other words, is a chain of logic unique and pure? Or is it like the law where when you present very convincing evidence in a court case, there could still be some doubt? Is there some set of rules that make a proof unique and universally understood by a machine?

You could present a proof at the most extreme detail and go into the most fundamental axioms of mathematics, or you could skip key points and just say "*clearly, this and that is the case*".

My second question is with respect to the format. I always see proofs with text and equations, but you also instead show a graph or a truth table or a drawing. Do illustrations also qualify as proofs (if they are presented in isolation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof should be unambiguously clear to the intended audience. It should leave no room for doubt. To a student who is first studying proofs, it would be a bad idea to confuse an illustration with a formal proof, because that leaves them in doubt as to whether the question has been been rigorously adressed. A professional mathematician who is well-versed in classical arguments, tricks and lingo can fill in the technical gaps left by a picture or proof sketch. Therefore, a drawing can stand as a proof to a professional audience, provided they can interpret it unequivocally.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your second question is "yes."  See, for example, [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_without_words) on proof without words.

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases, a mathematical proof is a form of communication to other mathematicians. In that sense, anything that effectively conveys the idea of the proof to the recipient in a convincing manner is a legitimate format.

In the study of formal logic, things may be a little different: I have heard the field described as "any mathematics in which proofs are manipulated as mathematical objects in their own right". In such a context, what constitutes a proof may be a good deal stricter – one may come up with definitions along the lines of "a proof in the predicate calculus is a finite sequence of logical formulae, each constructed from its predecessors by one of the following rules..." or "a proof of a proposition in this type system is a value inhabiting a type corresponding to that proposition". The verification of such proofs is then a purely mechanical, automatable process, which is reassuring, but they may be [impractically clumsy for some theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_tree_theorem).

Comment: Why the link to Kruskal's tree theorem?

Comment: Friedman's finite form of it can be proven for each $n$ in Peano Arithmetic, but the shortest possible proof grows impossibly fast, so you wouldn't be able to verify such a proof in a purely mechanical way.

Comment: But the verification is still "efficient" (i.e. polynomial in the input); in this case you are looking at a family of *proofs* that grow very fast. Presumably the verification is not much harder than the length of the proof (which itself grows super-exponentially as a function of $n$).